# Restricting type parameter base class through polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism

This is my inheritence chain. There are two of them. One for animals and the other one for animal behaviour.

```
AnimalBaseClass
|- Reptile 
|           |-  Crocodile
|           |- Snake
|
|- Mammals
            |- Apes
            |- Felines



AnimalBehaviourBaseClass
 |- ReptileBehaviour 
 |             
 |             
 |
 |- MammalBehaviour
```

AnimalBaseClass has a method called SetCurrentBehaviour with a type parameter.

I would want to have a AnimalBehaviourBaseClass that has methods that all behaviours have in common.
This is inherited by both ReptileBehaviour and MammalBehaviour classes.

The classes inheriting from AnimalBaseClass should only be able to set behaviours of its animal class. So Crocodile and snake can only accept ReptileBehaviour and classes derived from it. And Apes and Felines can only accept MammalBehaviour and classes deriving from it.

But the actual SetCurrentBehaviour method is the same for all animals. Is it somehow possibly to through polymorphism change the type requirement so that this is enforced? 
In the AnimalBaseClass it should the SetCurrentBehaviour

in Reptile it should be SetCurrentBehaviour
and in Mammals SetCurrentBehaviour

Of cours i could add methods to Reptile and Mammal classes but then the original SetCurrentBehaviour från AnimalBaseClass would still be there.

Maybe i am not thinking about this correctly according to OOP and C#?

Comment: 1. `class AnimalBaseClass<TBehaviour> where TBehaviour : AnimalBehaviourBaseClass` 2. `class Reptile<TBehaviour> : AnimalBaseClass<TBehaviour> where TBehaviour : ReptileBehaviour` 3. `class Crocodile : Reptile<CrocodileBehaviour>`

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are trying to do (`SetCurrentBehaviour` of each class accepts different types) won't achieve what you actually want (only be able to set behaviours to the corresponding type of animal).

Let's say I assigned an instance of `Crocodile` to a `AnimalBaseClass` variable:

```
AnimalBaseClass abc = someCrocodile;
```

Then, I call `abc.SetCurrentBehaviour` like this:

abc.SetCurrentBehaviour(new MammalBehaviour());

This is completely acceptable by the compiler. `abc` is of compile time type `AnimalBaseClass`, so its `SetCurrentBehaviour` accepts a `AnimalBehaviourBaseClass`. `MammalBehaviour` is one of its subclasses, so everything is fine by the compiler. But obviously, you don't want this.

One way to solve this is to introduce a generic type parameter to `AnimalBaseClass`, called `TBehaviour`:

```
class AnimalBaseClass<TBehaviour> where TBehaviour : AnimalBehaviourBaseClass {
    public void SetCurrentBehaviour(TBehaviour b) { ... } // note the type of parameter
}
```

In the animal subclasses, do something like this:

```
class Reptile : AnimalBaseClass<ReptileBehaviour>
class Mammal : AnimalBaseClass<MammalBehaviour>
```